# how are these two variables unpacked?

Tags: python, variables

Through tutorials I had learned that you can define two variables in the same statement, e.g.:

```
In [15]: a, b = 'hello', 'hi!'

In [16]: a
Out[16]: 'hello'

In [17]: b
Out[17]: 'hi!'
```

well how does that apply to here?

```
fh, opened = cbook.to_filehandle(fname, 'w', return_opened = True)
```

I prodded further:

```
In [18]: fh
Out[18]: <open file 'attempt.csv', mode 'w' at 0xaac89d0>

In [19]: opened
Out[19]: True
```

my issue comes really with 'opened'.  Well normally if two variables are being defined, there would be a comma and then whatever is there would define 'opened.'  This is not the case.  Even with that issue looming, 'opened' is equal to True which I assume is because 'return_opened = True.'  Well that's weird because I don't remember in any tutorial that you could just add a 'return_' before a variable to affect that variable.

I play with it some more and I change the True to False and I get this:

```
In [10]: fh, opened = cbook.to_filehandle(fname, 'w', return_opened = False)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/blahblahblah/Documents/Programming/EXERCISES/piece.py in <module>()
----> 1 
      2 
      3 
      4 
      5 

IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

so I guess it only accepts False.

I guess I'd like if someone could explain what is going on here.

Gracias amigos!

here's the entire code:

```
if missingd is None:
    missingd = dict()

def with_mask(func):
    def newfunc(val, mask, mval):
        if mask:
            return mval
        else:
            return func(val)
    return newfunc

formatd = get_formatd(r, formatd)
funcs = []
for i, name in enumerate(r.dtype.names):
    funcs.append(with_mask(csvformat_factory(formatd[name]).tostr))

fh, opened = cbook.to_filehandle(fname, 'w', return_opened=True)
writer = csv.writer(fh, delimiter=delimiter)
header = r.dtype.names
writer.writerow(header)

# Our list of specials for missing values
mvals = []
for name in header:
    mvals.append(missingd.get(name, missing))

ismasked = False
if len(r):
    row = r[0]
    ismasked = hasattr(row, '_fieldmask')

for row in r:
    if ismasked:
        row, rowmask = row.item(), row._fieldmask.item()
    else:
        rowmask = [False] * len(row)
    writer.writerow([func(val, mask, mval) for func, val, mask, mval
                     in zip(funcs, row, rowmask, mvals)])
if opened:
    fh.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @dcrosta says, there is nothing magical about the variable names. To better see what's going on, try:

```
result = cbook.to_filehandle(fname, 'w', return_opened=True)
```

and examine `result`, `type(result)`, etc: you'll see it's a tuple (could conceivably be a list or other sequence, but that's not likely) with exactly two items. `result[0]` will be an open file, `result[1]` will be a bool. Most likely, that's because function `to_filehandle` is coded with a `return thefile, thebool`-like statement, as dcrosta also surmises.

So, this part is "packing" -- two things are packed into one return value, making the latter a tuple with two items.  The "unpacking" part is when you later do:

```
fh, opened = result
```

and the two-item sequence is unpacked into two variables.  By doing the unpacking directly, you're just "cutting out the middleman", the variable I here named `result` (to make it easier for you to examine exactly what result comes from that function call, before it gets unpacked). If you know in advance you'll always get a 2-item sequence, and don't need the sequence as such but rather each item with a separate name, then you might as well unpack at once and save one "intermediate step" -- that's all there is to it!

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the function internally looks something like this:

```
def to_filehandle(filename, mode, return_opened=False):
    # do something to open the file and set opened
    # to True if it worked, False otherwise
    if return_opened:
        return the_filehandle, opened
    else:
        return the_filehandle
```

There is nothing special or magical about the `return_opened` keyword argument; it is simply changing the behavior of this particular function.

Answer (score 2):

With tuple assignment, the right side doesn't need to be an explicit tuple:

```
x = 1, 0
a, b = x
```

does the same thing as:

```
a, b = 1, 0
```

If a function returns a tuple, you can unpack it with tuple assignment:

```
def my_fn():
    return 1, 0

a, b = my_fn()
```

Answer (score 1):

Unpacking is not a magic process : every tuple (for example, `(1, 2, 3)` is a tuple with three values) can be unpacked into three values. But the tuple itself is also a value, so you can assign it to a variable or return it from a function :

```
x = (1, 2, 3)
a, b, c = x

# Or, for example :
def function_returning_a_tuple():
    return (True, False)

a, b = function_returning_a_tuple()
```

As you may now understand, `cbook.to_filehandle` is only a function returning a tuple of two values `(file, opened)`. There is no magic behind that, nothing about `return_something` parameters handled differently.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, a function have more than one return value. In this case, the function '`cbook.to_filehandle`' return the two value.

About the error, I think we cannot tell much about it until we know what '`cbook.to_filehandle`' supposes to do or see it code.